# remove jQuery expando

Tags: jquery, html, drupal

I have a problem I'm working on which is in Drupal unfortunately.  Since Drupal requires jQuery 1.5 for the admin panel, from my understanding but we are also using jQuery 1.8 for the newer functionality and Foundation 3

This issue is that everything works great except for in IE8 (yes I know).  Custom Form Dropdowns sometimes trigger the click event and sometimes do not.  I've narrowed it down to the event handler or expando that jQuery 1.5 adds dynamically to HTML elements.  When I remove the expando in the console the click event triggers every time.

I've tried multiple solutions where regex is done and using functions also using

```
$('#myelement').removeAttr($.expando)
```

and

```
$('#myelement').removeData($.expando)
```

as well as other functions people have created to deal with this but nothing seems to work.  When I console the expando it returns the correct value.  Even though I seem to put this code right before the `</body>` tag, adding a delay/setTimeout and still no dice.  I've spent multiple hours trying different solutions and researching.

Comment: have you tried puting it into the window.onload js function?

Comment: I have tried window.load and document.ready and still doesn't work.